# Short but frequent jobs: HandlerThread or ThreadPoolExecutor?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

First of all, I could not determine what the title should be, so if it's not specific enough, the question itself will be.

We have an application that uses a foreground service and stays alive forever, and in this service, there are frequent database access jobs, network access jobs and some more, that needs to run on background threads. One job itself consumes a small amount of time, but the jobs themselves are frequent. Obviously, they need to run on worker threads, so I'm here to ask which design we should follow.

[`HandlerThread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread) is a structure that creates a singular thread and uses a queue to execute tasks but always loops and waits for messages which consumes power, while [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor) creates multiple threads for each job and deletes threads when the jobs are done, but because of too many threads there could be leaks, or out-of-memory even. The job count may be 5, or it may be 20, depending on how the user acts in a certain way. And, between 2 jobs, there can be a 5 second gap, or a day gap, totally depending on user. But, remember, the application stays alive forever and waits for these jobs to execute.

So, for this specific occasion, which one is better to use? A thread pool executor or a handler thread? Any advice is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Caveat: I do not do Android work, so I am no expert there. My opinions here are based a quick reading of Android documentation.

## tl;dr

➥ Use Executors rather than `HandlerThread`.

The *Executors* framework is more modern, flexible, and powerful than the legacy `Thread` facility used by `HandlerThread`. Everything you can do in *HandlerThread* you can do better with executors.

## Differences

One big difference between [`HandlerThread`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread) and [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor) is that the first comes from Android while the second comes from Java. So if you'll be doing other work with Java, you might not want to get in the habit of using `HandlerThread`.

Another big difference is age. The `android.os.HandlerThread` class inherits from `java.lang.Thread`, and dates back to the original Android API level 1. While nice for its time, the `Thread` facility in Java is limited in its design. That facility was supplanted by the more modern, flexible, and powerful [*Executors* framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) in later Java.

## Executors

Your Question is not clear about whether these are recurring jobs or sporadically scheduled. Either can be handled with Executors.

For jobs that run once at a specific time, and for recurring scheduled jobs, use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). You can schedule a job to run once at a certain time by specifying a delay, a span of time to wait until execution. For repeated jobs, you can specify an amount to wait, then run, then wait, then run, and so on. I'll not address this further, as you seem to be talking about sporadic immediate jobs rather than scheduled or repeating jobs. If interested, search Stack Overflow as `ScheduledExecutorService` has been covered many times already on Stack Overflow.

### Single thread pool

> HandlerThread is a structure that creates a singular thread

If you want to recreate that single thread behavior, use a [thread pool consisting of only a single thread](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor()).

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() ;
```

Make your tasks. Implement either [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) or [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html) using (a) a class implementing either interface, (b) without defining a class, via lambda syntax or conventional syntax.

Conventional syntax.

```
Runnable sayHelloJob = new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run ( )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello. " + Instant.now() );
    }
};
```

Lambda syntax.

```
Runnable sayBonjourJob = ( ) -> System.out.println( "Bonjour. " + Instant.now() );
```

Submit as many of these jobs to the executor service as you wish.

```
es.submit( sayHelloJob ) ;
es.submit( sayBonjourJob ) ;
```

Notice that the `submit` method returns a [`Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html). With that `Future` object, you can check if the computation is complete, wait for its completion, or retrieve the result of the computation. Or you may choose to ignore the `Future` object as seen in the code above.

### Fixed thread pool

If you want multiple thread behavior, just create your executor with a different kind of thread pool.

A [fixed thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool(int)) has a maximum number of threads servicing a single queue of submitted jobs (`Runnable` or `Callable` objects). The threads continue to live, and are replaced as needed in case of failure.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool​( 3 ) ;  // Specify number of threads.
```

The rest of the code remains the same. That is the beauty of using the `ExecutorService` interface: You can change the implementation of the executor service to get difference behavior while not breaking your code that calls upon that executor service.

### Cached thread pool

Your needs may be better service by a [cached thread pool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool()). Rather than immediately creating and maintaining a certain number of threads as the fixed thread pool does, this pool creates threads only as needed, up to a maximum. When a thread is done, and resting for over a minute, the thread is terminated. As the Javadoc notes, this is ideal for “many short-lived asynchronous tasks” such as yours. But notice that there is no upper limit of threads that may be running simultaneously. If the nature of your app is such that you may see often spikes of many jobs arriving simultaneously, you may want to use a different implementation other than cached thread pool.

```
ExecutorService es = Executors.newCachedThreadPool() ;
```

## Managing executors and threads

> but because of too many threads there could be leaks, or out-of-memory even

It is the job of you the programmer and your sysadmin to not overburden the production server. You need to monitor performance in production. The managagement is easy enough to perform, as you control the number of threads available in the thread pool backing your executor service.

> We have an application that uses a foreground service and stays alive forever

Of course your app does eventually come to end, being shutdown. When that happens, be sure to shutdown your executor and its backing thread pool. Otherwise the threads may survive, and continue indefinitely. Be sure to use the life cycle hooks of your app’s execution environment to detect and react to the app shutting down.

> The job count may be 5, or it may be 20, depending on how the user acts in a certain way.

Jobs submitted to an executor service are buffered up until they can be scheduled on a thread for execution. So you may have a thread pool of, for example, 3 threads and 20 waiting jobs. No problem. The waiting jobs will be eventually executed when their time comes.

You may want to prioritize certain jobs, to be done ahead of lower priority jobs. One easy way to do this is to have *two* executor services. Each executor has its own backing thread pool. One executor is for the fewer but higher-priority jobs, while the other executor is for the many lower-priority jobs.

Remember that threads in a thread pool doing no work, on stand-by, have **virtually no overhead** in Java for either CPU or memory. So there is no downside to having a special higher-priority executor service sitting around and waiting for eventual jobs to arrive. The only concern is that your total number of all background threads and their workload not overwhelm your machine. Also, the implementation of the thread pool may well shut down unused threads after a period of disuse.

Comment: I like this answer, it's detailed enough for me to choose executors over a handler thread. I analyzed the usage for our case and at most the pool created 5 threads, and each of them are getting killed after 60 seconds, using `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`, if not used. Additionally, I chose to use daemon threads with a `ThreadFactory` to not hang the virtual machine, to reclaim the memory that it uses with killing those threads, in case `ExecutorService.shutdown()` cannot be called.

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul Certainly you may want to take the extra step of using a `ThreadFactory`. But I suggest you avoid the risk of [premature optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). Do not take that extra step until you have demonstrably proven a problem exists. Modern JVMs are highly-tuned and extremely performant.

Comment: Well, modern JVMs may be performant but, our applications target the audience of a 5-year old mobile phones (until Android 4.2.2 I mean), so everything needs to stay optimized as much as possible. And, unlikely, there is nothing to be done if a process dies abruptly, so I believe it is safer to use `Thread.setDaemon(true)` on those threads that the executor uses.

Answer (score 0):

Don't really think its a question of the number of threads you are running, more how you want them run. If you want them run one at at time (i.e. you only want to execute on database query at a time) then use a `HandlerThread`. If you want multi-threading / a pool of threads, then use and `Executor`.

In my experience, leaks are really more down to how you have coded your threads, not really the chosen implementation.

Personally, I'd use a `HandlerThread`, here's a nice article on implementing them and how to avoid memory leaks ... [Using HandlerThread in Android](https://medium.com/@frank.tan/using-handlerthread-in-android-46c285936fdd)

Comment: The problem begins when these tasks are going to be executed. As stated in the question, it might be a 5 second gap, or **a day** gap, which would cause the handler thread to run unnecessarily, consuming power. However, if the gap would be 5 seconds only, then using a singular thread (e.g. the handler thread) would have been a nice approach than creating new ones per job. So, I'm stumped.

Comment: @Furkan, well you could also just set-up a mechanism that destroys your handler if there is no more work for it and starts it up when you need it.  I would actually assumed that a `Executor` would use more power because it needs to maintain the pool of threads.  Also have a look this Android Developer page that specifically talks about [Performance](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads#internals), it does not speak about power usage, but does also seem to suggest that a `HandlerThread` is the better option, especially given your requirement.